# Как не допустить отправку формы после нажатия enter?

Tags: javascript, angular2

У меня есть реактивная форма:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="line">
    <input class="title" id="title" placeholder="Заголовок вопроса" type="text" formControlName="title">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <textarea class="question" name="question" id="question" placeholder="Текст вопроса" formControlName="question" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <div class="tags">
      <span class="title">Метки</span>
      <span class="tag" *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{ tag }} <span class="delete" (click)="deleteTag(tag)">X</span></span>
    </div>
    <input class="tag" id="tag" placeholder="Введите тег и нажмите enter" type="text" formControlName="tag" #tag (keyup.enter)="addTag($event, tag.value)">
  </div>

  <div class="line">
    <button class="btn btn-common" type="submit" mat-button [disabled]="form.invalid">
      Отправить
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

js:

```
private form: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'title':      new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1)]),
      'question':   new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
      'tag':        new FormControl()
    });
  }
```

поле с id='tag' я использую для добавления тегов. Порядок такой: пользователь вводит в это поле название тега и нажимает enter. Проблема в том, что после нажатия enter происходит отправка формы, а я хотел бы этого избежать.

на это поле через `(keyup.enter)="addTag($event, tag.value)` я повесил обработчик такой:

```
  private addTag(event, tag): void {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if(!tag.trim().length) { return; }

    this.form.patchValue({tag: ''});

    if(this.tags.indexOf(tag) === -1) {
      this.tags.push(tag.trim());
    }
  }
```

Как видите, в первых строках происходит отмена стандартного действия и отмена всплытия события. Но это не срабатывает в ангуляре. При этом объект события в консоль выводится

Comment: Я почти не знаю ангуляр, однако тут на стаковерфлоу я поставил курсор в поле поиск и нажал (!не отпуская)  энтер. Поиск сработал. Таком образом я думаю событие, которое вам нужно - keydown

Comment: А вообще наверное будет лучше перехватывать событие onsubmit, так как вариантов сабмита формы больше, чем один

Comment: вот тут пишут (пост Evgeny Kokhanovsky ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549985/prevent-form-submission-on-enter-key

Comment: Daniel Khoroshko, ну там же для первого ангуляра пишут

Comment: понятно, но события то все теже :-)

Comment: вот там и говорят - onkeydown надо https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040023/how-intercept-submit-form =D

Comment: onkeydown ничего не меняет. я пробовал

Comment: Надо на `onSubmit` ставить отмену события.